# adding contact phone numbers to multiple uitextfiels

Tags: iphone, uitextview, abaddressbook

I have a uibutton that  when tapped brings up the contacts list and adds the selected phone number to a uitextfield.Here's the code i am using.

```
- (IBAction)contact1:(id)sender
{
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker1 =
[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker1.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker1 animated:YES];
}
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

 (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
  [self displayPerson:person];
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  return NO;
  }


 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

 (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
 shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
 property:(ABPropertyID)property
 identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier

 {
 return NO;
 }

- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
 {
NSString* phone = nil;
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

 } else {
    phone = @"[None]";
    }
 self.telField1.text = phone;
 }
```

What I am trying to do is have multiple uibuttons add phone numbers to multiple uitextfield's.

for example:    contact1 button adds phone# to telField1
               contact2 button adds phone# to telField2 
               contact3 button adds phone# to telField3

each textfield would have a different phone#.

can my original code be tweeked or is there another method i should try?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)getContact {
// creating the picker
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the controll
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

// showing the picker
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
// releasing
[picker release];
```

}

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
// assigning control back to the main controller
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

```
  - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

// setting the first name
firstName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

// setting the last name
lastName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);   

ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
number.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);

// remove the controller
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

return NO;
```

}

```
  - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
return NO;
```

}

It will show contacts in textfield with the click of a button, no need to set separate button for each textfield.

Comment: I don't see how this could add the tel number to the specific textfield I have chosen.

Comment: I will give you the link of example tomorrow.